# difference between two menu links on jquery navbar

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to create a simple navbar using jquery mobile, but it seems to look odd on the desktop.

[image: http://imgur.com/7BIgUQx]

When I jump to the starting page "./overview", the entire menu is bigger and has a strange line going threw it.  If I click on the second menu item, the menu gets smaller and looks correct.  I went to see if I could reproduce it in firefox and noticed its not unique to the overview page.  If I type "./stats" after the domain, it goes to the stats page and the menu is again rendered differently.  Going back to the overview page, the menu looks normal.  So what seems to be happening is the menu looks wrong only on the page that I entered in the url bar.  If I switch to the other page, the url updates in the bar, but it looks fine.  Switching back with the menu, the menu gets big again with that line threw it.

I've looked at the source for both pages and they look identical, so I don't know what else to check.

**overview**

```
<html>
  <header>
    <title>Overview</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
  </header>
  <body>
    <h1>Overview</h1>
    <h3></h3>

    <div data-role="header" data-id="foo1" data-position="fixed">
      <div data-role="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/10/overview" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">Overview</a></li>
      <li><a href="/10/stats">Status</a></li>
    </ul>
      </div><!-- /navbar -->
    </div><!-- /footer -->
  </body>
</html>
```

**stats**

```
<html>
  <header>
    <title>Stats</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
  </header>
  <body>
    <h1>Stats</h1>
    <h3></h3>

    <div data-role="header" data-id="foo1" data-position="fixed">
      <div data-role="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/10/overview">Overview</a></li>
      <li><a href="/10/stats" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">Stats</a></li>
    </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Does anyone know what causes this menu enlargement?

Comment: can you provide live working link for this if possible or fiddle?

Comment: I tried in fiddle and it looks normal. Check overview fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2e84d/ and stats fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/QSyhq/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include below tags in between head tag in both the pages:

```
<title>Stats</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
```